# Python packages directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

Today I read this guide: https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/#inst-custom-install. Nowhere in this document did I found information about the directory `dist-packages` and in the same moment this document states that the default value of standard installation location is `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`. This puzzles me, because what I found is that a path: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` is the default one for the `pip install some_package`.

On contrast everything works just as described in previously mentioned document when I'm using `virtualenv`.

My question is: where are all those differences comming from and what are the reasons behind them.

NOTE: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find anything about that in the Python docs, because it is a Debian-specific customization (which is inherited by Ubuntu since that is based on Debian). See [their wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Python#Deviations_from_upstream) for a bit of explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this link - it clears the situation for me. I was searching in the wrong places :)